# Ruby on Rails - Get first n number of elements from array with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

In my Rails view template, the @comments is an array of hashes. I just need to show the first three comments that  meet this condition <% if post["id"] === comment["postId"] %>. Right now it's showing all of them.

```
 <tbody>
            <% @posts.each do |post| %>
                <tr>
                    <% @users.each do |user| %>
                            <% if post["userId"] === user["id"] %>
                                <td> <%= user["name"]  %></td>
                            <% end %>
                        <% end %>
                        <td><%= post["title"]  %></td>
                        <td><%= post["body"]  %></td>
                        <% comments_total = 0 %>
                        <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
                            <% if post["id"] === comment["postId"] %>
                                <td><%= comment["body"] %></td>
                                <% comments_total += 1 %>
                            <% end %>
                        <% end %>
                        <td><%= comments_total %></td>
                    <% end %>
                                
                </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: You might want to keep track of how many you've rendered, then, and stop after three. Tangentially related: it might be better to do the bulk of this work before hitting the view layer; it will allow you to only grab the number of comments you actually need to display, and the total, using fast DB queries instead of iterating *all* comments, which here don't appear to be associated to the post in question.

Comment: In other words, Rails gives you a fair amount of magic--make use of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would you get the data from different API edpoints and associate them? I am fetching three different endpoints (user, posts, comments), and I have to display, for instance, all the users with their last three posts and their comments. Again, having all the data from external API. I could really use some help knowing how.

Comment: Oh, that's a different matter--there's no way to know w/o knowing anything about the API. Hopefully there's a mechanism for not just fetching everything, or for fetching related data using relationship information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you only want to show the first 3 comments that match a certain condition then I would do this:

```
<% matching_comments = @comments.select { |comment| comment["postId"] == post["id"] } %>
<% matching_comments.first(3).each do |comment| %>
  <td><%= comment["body"] %></td>
<% end %>
<td><%= matching_comments.size %></td>
```

You might load the @comments with the condition in the controller to make the view easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would you get the data from different API edpoints and associate them? I am fetching three different endpoints (user, posts, comments), and I have to display, for instance, all the users with their last three posts and their comments. Again, having all the data from external API. I could really use some help knowing how.

Comment: That depends entirely on how the APIs were built. The API might, for example, only allow loading single records, or it might support loading records matching a list of foreign keys, or it might even allow returning nested records. Without public documentation of the API, it is impossible for us to help you.